# Why must a lambda expression be cast when supplied as a plain Delegate parameter

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, delegates, lambda

Take the method System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)

Why does this give a compile time error:

```
string str = "woop";
Invoke(() => this.Text = str);
// Error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate'
// because it is not a delegate type
```

Yet this works fine:

```
string str = "woop";
Invoke((Action)(() => this.Text = str));
```

When the method expects a plain Delegate?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

A lambda expression can either be converted to a delegate type or an expression tree - but it has to know *which* delegate type. Just knowing the signature isn't enough. For instance, suppose I have:

```
public delegate void Action1();
public delegate void Action2();

...

Delegate x = () => Console.WriteLine("hi");
```

What would you expect the concrete type of the object referred to by `x` to be? Yes, the compiler *could* generate a new delegate type with an appropriate signature, but that's rarely useful and you end up with less opportunity for error checking.

If you want to make it easy to call `Control.Invoke` with an `Action` the easiest thing to do is add an extension method to Control:

```
public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
{
    control.Invoke((Delegate) action);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I updated the question because I think untyped was the wrong term to use.

Comment: That is a very elegant and mature solution. I'd probably call it "InvokeAction" so that the name suggests what we're actually invoking (instead of a generic delegate) but it certainly works for me :)

Comment: I disagree that it's "rarely useful and ...". In the case of calling Begin/Invoke with a lambda you certainly don't care if the delegate type is auto-generated, we just want to get the call made. In what situation would a method that accepts a Delegate (the base type) care what the concrete type is? Also, what is the purpose of the extension method? It doesn't make anything easier.

Comment: @Tergiver: The extension method certainly *does* make things easier. You can just call `control.Invoke(() => DoStuff)` because there *is* a conversion from the lambda expression to `Action`. Doesn't that do exactly what we want? As whether the "autogenerated" delegate is useful - I'd argue that the problem here is that `Delegate` really isn't appropriate in the first place. What should `Control.Invoke` pass in if you give it a delegate with 10 parameters? It was the best option available in .NET 1, but with generics there are better approaches IMO.

Comment: Ah! I added the extension method and tried `Invoke(()=>DoStuff)` and still got the error. The problem was that I used the implicit 'this'. To get it to work from within a Control member you have to be explicit: `this.Invoke(()=>DoStuff)`.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, I think the question&answers to [C#: Automating the InvokeRequired code pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2367763/209259) are very helpful.

Comment: Thats a good answer! Similarly you can't cast an anonymous delegate directly to LambdaExpression, instead one has to cast with the exact expression with types specified

Answer (score 35):

Tired of casting lambdas over and over?

```
public sealed class Lambda<T>
{
    public static Func<T, T> Cast = x => x;
}

public class Example
{
    public void Run()
    {
        // Declare
        var c = Lambda<Func<int, string>>.Cast;
        // Use
        var f1 = c(x => x.ToString());
        var f2 = c(x => "Hello!");
        var f3 = c(x => (x + x).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a beautiful use of generics.

Comment: I'll have to admit, this took me awhile to figure out why it worked.  Brilliant.  Too bad I have no use for it right now.

Comment: Can you please explain the usage of this?  Its difficult for me to comprehend this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Its to ever read this let alone say it but i think i prefer this answer to Jon Skeet's!

Comment: @shahkalpesh its not very complex. See it this way, the `Lambda<T>` class has an identity conversion method called `Cast`, which returns whatever is passed (`Func<T, T>`). Now the `Lambda<T>` is declared as `Lambda<Func<int, string>>` which means if you pass a `Func<int, string>` to `Cast` method, it returns `Func<int, string>` back, since `T` in this case is `Func<int, string>`.

Comment: So now variable `c` is the delegate to the `Cast` function. It takes input of `T` which is `Func<int, string>`, so those are passed as arguments in the form of lambda (`c(.. => ...)`) which returns the same back which `f1`, `f2` etc knows. Basically you're relying on compiler's inferring mechanism.

Answer (score 12):

Nine tenths of the time people get this because they are trying to marshal onto the UI thread. Here's the lazy way:

```
static void UI(Action action) 
{ 
  System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(action); 
}
```

Now that it's typed, the problem goes away (qv Skeet's anwer) and we have this very succinct syntax:

```
int foo = 5;
public void SomeMethod()
{
  var bar = "a string";
  UI(() =>
  {
    //lifting is marvellous, anything in scope where the lambda
    //expression is defined is available to the asynch code
    someTextBlock.Text = string.Format("{0} = {1}", foo, bar);        
  });
}
```

For bonus points here's another tip. You wouldn't do this for UI stuff but in cases where you need SomeMethod to block till it completes (eg request/response I/O, waiting for the response) use a [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f7e54k1.aspx) (qv msdn WaitAll, WaitAny, WaitOne).

Note that AutoResetEvent is a WaitHandle derivative.

```
public void BlockingMethod()
{
  AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((state) =>
  {
    //do asynch stuff        
    are.Set();
  });      
  are.WaitOne(); //don't exit till asynch stuff finishes
}
```

And a final tip because things can get tangled: WaitHandles stall the thread. This is what they're supposed to do. If you try to marshal onto the UI thread *while you have it stalled*, your app will hang. In this case (a) some serious refactoring is in order, and (b) as a temporary hack you can wait like this:

```
  bool wait = true;
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((state) =>
  {
    //do asynch stuff        
    wait = false;
  });
  while (wait) Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Comment: I find it fascinating that people have the cheek to vote down an answer merely because they personally don't find it appealing. If it's *wrong* and you know this, then say what's wrong with it. If you can't do so, then you have no basis for a downvote. If it's epically wrong then say something like "Baloney. See [correct response]" or perhaps "Not a recommended solution, see [better stuff]"

Comment: Yes, I am the frankenthreadstress; but anyway I have no idea why it was voted down; although I haven't used the actual code, I thought this was a nice quick intro to UI cross-thread invokes, and it has some things I hadn't really thought of so kudos, definitely +1 for going above and beyond. :) 

I mean, you gave a nice quick method for making delegate invokes; you give an option for calls which must be waited on; and you follow it up with a nice quick way for someone who is stuck in UI Thread Hell to get a bit of control back. Fine answer, I am gonna say +<3 as well. :)

Comment: `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` will return the CURRENT thread's dispatcher -- i.e. if you call this method from a thread that is not the UI thread, the code will not be run on the UI thread.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 good point, probably the best thing is for an app to capture a reference to the UI thread dispatcher on and put it somewhere globally accessible. I'm amazed it took this long for someone to notice that!

Answer (score 4):

Peter Wone. you are da man.
Taking your concept a bit further, I came up with these two functions.

```
private void UIA(Action action) {this.Invoke(action);}
private T UIF<T>(Func<T> func) {return (T)this.Invoke(func);}
```

I place these two functions into my Form app, and I can make calls from background workers like this

```
int row = 5;
string ip = UIF<string>(() => this.GetIp(row));
bool r = GoPingIt(ip);
UIA(() => this.SetPing(i, r));
```

Maybe a bit lazy, but i don't have to setup worker done functions, 
which comes in super handy in cases such as this

```
private void Ping_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  int count = this.dg.Rows.Count;
  System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, count, i => 
  {
    string ip = UIF<string>(() => this.GetIp(i));
    bool r = GoPingIt(ip);
    UIA(() => this.SetPing(i, r));
  });
  UIA(() => SetAllControlsEnabled(true));
}
```

Essentially, get some ip addresses from a gui DataGridView, ping them, set the resulting icons to green or red, and reenable buttons on the form. Yes, it is a "parallel.for" in a backgroundworker. Yes it is a LOT of invoking overhead, but its negligible for short lists, and much more compact code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to build this upon [@Andrey Naumov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714044/661933)'s answer. May be this is a slight improvement.

```
public sealed class Lambda<S>
{
    public static Func<S, T> CreateFunc<T>(Func<S, T> func)
    {
        return func;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<S, T>> CreateExpression<T>(Expression<Func<S, T>> expression)
    {
        return expression;
    }

    public Func<S, T> Func<T>(Func<S, T> func)
    {
        return func;
    }

    public Expression<Func<S, T>> Expression<T>(Expression<Func<S, T>> expression)
    {
        return expression;
    }
}
```

Where type parameter `S` is the formal parameter (the input parameter, which is minimum required to infer rest of the types). Now you can call it like:

```
var l = new Lambda<int>();
var d1 = l.Func(x => x.ToString());
var e1 = l.Expression(x => "Hello!");
var d2 = l.Func(x => x + x);

//or if you have only one lambda, consider a static overload
var e2 = Lambda<int>.CreateExpression(x => "Hello!");
```

You can have additional overloads for `Action<S>` and `Expression<Action<S>>` similarly in the same class. For *other* built in delegate and expression types, you will have to write separate classes like `Lambda`, `Lambda<S, T>`, `Lambda<S, T, U>` etc.

Advantage of this I see over the original approach:

1. One less type specification (only the formal parameter needs to be specified).
2. Which gives you the freedom to use it against any `Func<int, T>`, not just when `T` is say, `string`, as shown in examples.
3. Supports expressions straight away. In the earlier approach you will have to specify types again, like:

   ```
   var e = Lambda<Expression<Func<int, string>>>.Cast(x => "Hello!");

   //or in case 'Cast' is an instance member on non-generic 'Lambda' class:
   var e = lambda.Cast<Expression<Func<int, string>>>(x => "Hello!");
   ```

   for expressions.
4. Extending the class for other delegate (and expression) types is similarly cumbersome like above.

   ```
   var e = Lambda<Action<int>>.Cast(x => x.ToString());

   //or for Expression<Action<T>> if 'Cast' is an instance member on non-generic 'Lambda' class:
   var e = lambda.Cast<Expression<Action<int>>>(x => x.ToString());
   ```

In my approach you have to declare types only once (that too one less for `Func`s).

---

One another way to implement Andrey's answer is like not going fully generic

```
public sealed class Lambda<T>
{
    public static Func<Func<T, object>, Func<T, object>> Func = x => x;
    public static Func<Expression<Func<T, object>>, Expression<Func<T, object>>> Expression = x => x;
}
```

So things reduce to:

```
var l = Lambda<int>.Expression;
var e1 = l(x => x.ToString());
var e2 = l(x => "Hello!");
var e3 = l(x => x + x);
```

That's even less typing, but you lose certain type safety, and **imo, this is not worth it.**

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party but you can also cast like this

```
this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate {
    // do awesome stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { textBox1.Text = "Test 123"; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Playing with XUnit and [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/introduction) it was possible to use this inline capability in a way I find really cool.

**Before**

```
[Fact]
public void Pass_Open_Connection_Without_Provider()
{
    Action action = () => {
        using (var c = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient").CreateConnection())
        {
            c.ConnectionString = "<xxx>";
            c.Open();
        }
    };

    action.Should().Throw<Exception>().WithMessage("xxx");
}
```

**After**

```
[Fact]
public void Pass_Open_Connection_Without_Provider()
{
    ((Action)(() => {
        using (var c = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("<provider>").CreateConnection())
        {
            c.ConnectionString = "<connection>";
            c.Open();
        }
    })).Should().Throw<Exception>().WithMessage("Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers were correct at the time they were written, but starting from C# 10.0 (from 2021), the compiler *can* infer a suitable delegate type (like some `Func<...>`, `Action<...>` or generated delegate type) in such cases.

See [C# 10 Features - Lambda improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements).

```
string str = "woop";
Invoke(() => this.Text = str);   // OK in C# 10.0, in this case 'Func<string>' is picked
```

```
string str = "woop";
Invoke(() => { this.Text = str; });   // OK in C# 10.0, in this case 'Action' is picked
```

Comments assume the signature `Invoke(Delegate method)` as in your question. Of course if the method wants a particular (not abstract) delegate type, C# will attempt to convert the lambda into that one, as was also the case before C# 10.0.