# Thread safety issue: Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, datagridview, thread-safety

I am trying to listen on a device and when got a message from that showing it on a datagridview the first but getting the message from the device works perfectly, but the problem is that when I want to set the DGV content I got this exception  Cross-thread operation not valid, and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579854/c-sharp-thread-issues) related topic.
but none of them was helpful since there weren't on a binding DGV.
here is my code:
1. first I have a message class which is binded to the DGV,

```
public class Msg_log
{
    public Msg_log()
    {
        this.Event = null;
        this.Operator = null;
    }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how I create another thread in the loadform event:

```
newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(this.Event_Listener);
        newThread.Start();
```

and in the Event_Listener function

```
                x.Add(message);
                MsgDGV.DataSource = null;
                MsgDGV.DataSource = x;
                MsgDGV.Refresh();
```

the message object is like this:

```
Msg_log message = new Msg_log();
```

and its Event and Operator variables of message have been set correctly, and I put the MSG.DataSource = null, since I want to update my DGV after the new message is comming (Actually this was my idea and if there is any better way for that I would appreciate that) and that's the line I got the exeption:Cross-thread operation not valid. In the other posts I found out that I should use Invoke method but I don't know how to call Msg_DGV.Invoke(??,???); I don't know what should I pass to that to get the right result...
Cheers,

Comment: Create a method to handle set the DGV DataSource and Refresh to the DGV and call MsgDGV.Invoke(myDelegate,vnew Object[] {x});    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do want to do the same as that post you linked to, just change your control to use a DataGridView. [C# Thread issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579854/c-sharp-thread-issues)

```
Msg_DGV.Invoke(new Action( () => Msg_DGV.DataSource = null ) );
```

A more full blown example from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx) that doesn't use Actions.

```
// The declaration of the textbox.
private TextBox m_TextBox;

// Updates the textbox text.
private void UpdateText(string text)
{
  // Set the textbox text.
  m_TextBox.Text = text;
}

//Now, create a delegate that has the same signature as the method that was previously defined:
public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(string text);

//In your thread, you can call the Invoke method on m_TextBox, 
//passing the delegate to call, as well as the parameters.
m_TextBox.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateText), 
            new object[]{”Text generated on non-UI thread.”});
```

Comment: I made it sth like this and this helped I think:)
Action show_DGV = delegate()
                    {
                        MsgDGV.DataSource = null;
                        MsgDGV.DataSource = x;
                        MsgDGV.Refresh();
                    };
                    this.MsgDGV.Invoke(show_DGV);

Answer (score 1):

You could just use BackgroundWorker.

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (s, e) => {
                         ...
                         x.Add(message);
                         ...
                         e.Result = x;
                       };
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => MsgDGV.DataSource = e.Result;
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```