# How to get return value of function called from a Invoke method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, invoke

I need explanations.. why the following code give an: `Parameter count mismatch` ?

C# Code:

```
//... 
public delegate int FindInRichTextBoxMethod(RichTextBox rtx, string target, int index);
 public int FindInRichTextBox(RichTextBox rtx, string target, int index)
    {
        return rtx.Find(target, index, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    }
// ... 
int start; 
string tempState = "foo";

if (lista.InvokeRequired) {
  object find = Invoke((FindInRichTextBoxMethod)delegate
                            {
                                return FindInRichTextBox(list, tempState, len);
                            });  

                            start = (int)find;
} else {

      start = FindInRichTextBox(list, tempState, len);
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to [`Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx) include a delegate, and the arguments passed to that delegate.  You're attempting to pass a `FindInRichTextBoxMethod` delegate, but that delegate type takes three arguments.  You need to:

1. construct a delegate with your `FindInRichTextBox` method, and then
2. pass in the parameters to that delegate.

Something like this:

```
var finder = new FindInRichTextBoxMethod(FindInRichTextBox);
object find = Invoke(finder, new object[] { list, tempState, len });
```

---

Another route is to pass in a closure, sort of like you're attempting in your sample.  In your case the error is due to the cast to a `FindInRichTextBoxMethod`, so the Invoke is expecting arguments.  Instead, you could ignore the cast and pass in an anonymous delegate like this:

```
var find = Invoke(delegate { return FindInRichTextBox(list, tempState, len); });
```

This won't work, though, because the compiler can't determine exactly what you want to do with that anonymous delegate.  Similarly, a lambda can't be automatically converted either:

```
var find = Invoke(() => FindInRichTextBox(list, tempState, len));
```

To see why and how to fix the problem, read [Why must a lambda expression be cast when supplied as a plain Delegate parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411579/why-must-a-lambda-expression-be-cast-when-supplied-as-a-plain-delegate-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this in the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx) call?  I usually pass Invoke a delegate and then an object array containing the variables you want to pass.