# Extension method for a function

Tags: c#

I can create extension methods off any type.
Once such type is Func of int for example.

I want to write extension methods for functions, not the return type of functions.

I can do it in a hacky way:

```
Func<int> getUserId = () => GetUserId("Email");
int userId = getUserId.Retry(2);
```

Where the function Retry is an extension method defined as:

```
public static T Retry<T>(this Func<T> func, int maxAttempts)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Retries failed.");
}
```

What I really want to do is:

```
var userId = (() => GetUserId("Email")).Retry(2);
```

But the compiler doesn't reconcile the function as a Func of T.

I know of the static including in Roslyn, so I could do something like:

```
Retry(() => GetUserId("Email"), 2);
```

But I find this harder to read. I really want the helper function I create to be out of the way.

There are other patterns out there that would give me similar results, such as monadic expressions, or using chaining (i.e. convert T to a chain type, that internally has a T, and then I write extension methods for Chain of T). The problem I have with this approach is you have to start off the expression by casting to a Chain of T, and then end the expression by casting to T, which is a lot of noise pulling the reader's attention away from my business logic.

I know I could use implicit casting on Chain of T to T, but this feels like it's doing some magic behind the scenes.

So is it possible to get the reference to a function, without executing it first, with little to no boiler plate code?

End of the day I'd Like to write the following for any kind of Func / Action:

```
var settings = LoadSettingsFromDatabase().Retry(2);
```

Comment: Fluent API doesn't fit your requirement ?

Comment: You *know* that it's not possible to create an extension method for a lambda directly, because you've done it and seen the error.  At that point it simply comes down to the personal preference of what means of typing the lambda as a delegate that you personally prefer, which is simply a matter of opinion.  There are dozens of ways to do it; you've provided several.

Comment: @alsafoo Fluent API uses the chaining pattern, which I'm aware of but would rather avoid. I do use Fluent API for input validation, but wouldn't want to use it for business logic.

Comment: @Servy Yes I had that feeling, but I was hoping someone out there new this one simple trick to help me, or perhaps some kind of pattern I was unaware of.

Comment: @user1909158 Like I said, you could write dozens of methods to do this, you've shown quite a few yourself; which is "best" is purely personal preference.

Comment: @Servy Your correct, but my question is not which is best, it's is this pattern, or one very much like it possible? I showed these other examples to prove my research before I asked the question, and to clarify my question with similar approaches. It seems your answer to my question is "no, you can't do that that way", which is fine, but I'd like to take my chances with some creative people out there.

Comment: It's not possible because `(() => GetUserId("Email"))` cannot be implicitly resolved. It works when using `Retry(...)` because the compiler is able to match it to a possible type based on `Retry`'s arguments. In short - no, it's not possible, unless you wrap it like this: `var userID = new Func<int>(() => GetUserId("Email")).Retry(2)`

Comment: @Rob I think this deserves to be an answer

Comment: @user1909158 If you want to know if it's possible to call an extension method on *just* a lambda, with nothing else, all you need to do is compile it, which you did, see that it doesn't compile, which you did, and have your conclusive answer.  Are you expecting someone to tell you that the compiler is wrong in saying that that code won't compile?

Comment: @Servy Nope, just wondering there there was another way to do it, may be reflection, or something like that. I agree with Trailmax, Rob has the closest thing I think I'll ever get to an answer. Perhaps it's a bad question, that was doomed to fail from the beginning.

Comment: This library doesn't expose the exact API you want, but it may be worth looking at https://github.com/Aspenware/Hopefully

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167676/error-message-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operand-of-type-lambda-express), I think the answer is "no".

I would advise you go with a static include of `Retry`, as you suggested:

```
Retry(() => GetUserId("Email"), 2);
```

It makes intent clear, it's uncomplicated, it's readable enough, and it's idiomatic C#.

**An idea that I don't like:**

If you were willing to reverse your method arguments, the following would work (but I think most people would think it's pretty awful):

```
public static T AttemptsAt<T>(this int maxAttempts, Func<T> func)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Retries failed.");
}
```

Usage:

```
var userId = 2.AttemptsAt(() => GetUserId("Email"));
```

Comment: This is a nice solution(the idea you don't like),I was going to suggest it but you beat me to it

Comment: First time for me to consider this second (not recommended) solution. +1

Answer (score 4):

Of course if you need a one-liner, you will have to cast explicitly to the desired delegate type:

```
var userId = ((Func<int>)(() => GetUserId("Email"))).Retry(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the member method cannot implicitly cast itself to a Func - which to me seems odd, but maybe there is a good explanation :).

Anyway here is how i would call a Func extension:

```
var userId = ((Func<int>)GetUserId("Email")).Retry(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it answers your question but it seems possible to define an extension method of Func(or Action), see:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104555/The-Function-Decorator-Pattern-Reanimation-of-Func. To quote mr Jordan:

```
public static Func<TArg, TResult> RetryIfFailed<TArg, TResult>
                              (this Func<TArg, TResult> func, int maxRetry) {
return (arg) => {
    int t = 0;
    do {
        try {
            return func(arg);
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            if (++t > maxRetry) {
                throw;
            }
        }
    } while (true);
 };
}

  ....
  // get the method we are going to retry with
  Func<DateTime, string> getMyDate = client.GetMyDate;
  // intercept it with RetryIfFailed interceptor, which retries once at most
  getMyDate = getMyDate.RetryIfFailed(1);
  for (var i = 0; i < TimesToInvoke; i++) {
     try {
        // call the intercepted method instead of client.GetMyDate
        getMyDate(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i % 30));
        counter.TotalSuccess++;
     }
   catch (Exception ex) {counter.TotalError++; }
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to write an extension method that returns a Func:

```cs
public static Func<T, TResult> WithRetries<T, TResult>(this Func<T, TResult> func, int maxRetries)
```

And use it in the following way:

```cs
var getUserId = GetUserId;
int userId = getUserId.WithRetries(3)("Email");
```

Comment: Be aware that the line `var getUserId = GetUserId;` uses a feature of C# 10.0 (from 2021) which was not available when the question was asked (2016).