# Why can anonymous methods be implicitly passed as Action?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why must a lambda expression be cast when supplied as a plain Delegate parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411579/why-must-a-lambda-expression-be-cast-when-supplied-as-a-plain-delegate-parameter)

`Control.Invoke` accepts a `Delegate` parameter type.  I cannot pass a lamba expression as a `Delegate` without telling the compiler which type of delegate I'm passing.

`textBox1.Invoke(() => { MessageBox.Show("Hello World"); });  //illegal`

In this case, I can cast to `Action`

`textBox1.Invoke((Action)(() => { MessageBox.Show("Hello World"); }));  //legal`

However, I can create a shorthand method via an extension method (I've seen Marc Gravell do this):

```
public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
{
    control.Invoke((Delegate)action);
}
```

Now my shorthand works...

`textBox1.Invoke(() => { MessageBox.Show("Hello World"); });  //legal`

How is it that the compiler can determine that an anonymous method is an Action in the extension method, but the compiler cannot determine a lamba is an Action and therefore a legal `Delegate` in the case of `Control.Invoke`?

Comment: @DanielBruckner - That question is similar, but it does not address my question.  I am looking into two distinct, similar scenerios.  I want to understand why one case is implicit and the other case requires explicit.  I am asking about this specific incongruity, not the workaround...which I've already defined in the OP.  I suspect the answer has to do with Method Invocation.

Comment: I think Jon Skeet states it quite clearly - the compiler does not know the type of delegate to create because there can be several delegates with the same signature. For example `System.Predicate<T>` and `System.Func<T, Boolean>` have the same signature taking something of type `T` and returning `Boolean`. Now the compiler is just unable to figure out if `x => x == "something"` should become an instance of `Predicate<String>` or of `Func<String, Boolean>`.

Comment: @DanielBruckner - Ok...look at it this way.  What if I add more Extension Methods? Some with Expression tree overloads to create a clear ambiguity?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Try it and you'll get your answer.

Comment: You have to remember that `control.Invoke(() => DoSomething());` is syntactic sugar for `control.Invoke(new Action(CompilerGeneratedFunction));`. How can the compiler possibly come up with the class `Action` if the signature of `Control.Invoke` only states that the parameter is of type `Delegate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the compiler is smart enough to determine that the parameter is of type `Action` (as opposed to say `Action<T>`).  More importantly, the compiler can assume I mean an `Action` as opposed to an `Expression` because the ambiguity is removed.  If I do something silly to recreate ambiguity...say create an overload via a new extension method:

```
    public static void Invoke(this Control control, Expression<Action> action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
        //control.Invoke((Delegate)action);
    }
```

The compiler will catch that as well:

`The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:`

The comments made walked me to the answer I'm looking for.